# Why is PostgreSQL choosing this index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Preface - please, before marking as duplicate, I realize this general question has been asked and answered many times. I'm posing a very specific use case, which couldn't reasonably be conveyed in the question title, and looking for an answer specific to this case. With all due respect, please don't bother with speculative answers. I've speculated plenty, I'm looking for a definitive answer backed by specific knowledge or documentation of the PostgreSQL query planner.

Given this table and this query,

```
CREATE TABLE grouptest
(
  id1 int, id2 int, g1 int, g2 int, g3 int, t timestamp
);

CREATE INDEX idx_g2 ON grouptest (id1, id2, g1, g2, t);
CREATE INDEX idx_g3 ON grouptest (id1, id2, g2, g3, t);

EXPLAIN
SELECT g2
FROM grouptest
WHERE id1 = 123 AND id2 = 234 AND g1 = 1234;
```

To me, the obvious choice for the best index to use would be the first index `idx_g2`, as it exactly matches what's being queried. However, the query planner chooses the second index `idx_g3`.

```
Index Scan using idx_g3 on grouptest  (cost=0.15..8.18 rows=1 width=4)
  Index Cond: ((id1 = 123) AND (id2 = 234) AND (t >= '2021-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2021-03-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  Filter: (g1 = 1234)
```

Aside from not being the obvious choice, it even has to go to the table data to get the `g1` to filter, when it could have done an index-only scan on the first index. This is completely consistent. It will choose it every time, doesn't matter if I `discard plans`, run other queries in between that use the first index, etc. And I've tried this on several other and more complex tables/queries having the same general pattern, and got the same results. The example I'm showing just simplifies the use case down to its most basic form.

***But here's the shocker!*** If I create the indexes in the opposite order,

```
CREATE INDEX idx_g3 ON grouptest (id1, id2, g2, g3, t);
CREATE INDEX idx_g2 ON grouptest (id1, id2, g1, g2, t);
```

it chooses what I would consider the best index, `idx_g2`, and as I would expect, can do an index-only scan.

```
Index Only Scan using idx_g2 on grouptest  (cost=0.15..8.18 rows=1 width=4)
  Index Cond: ((id1 = 123) AND (id2 = 234) AND (g1 = 1234) AND (t >= '2021-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (t < '2021-03-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

Granted, there is no data in the table at this point, so no statistics that would push it in one direction over the other. And I'm sure some would say "Trust the query planner, it will make the best choice." And that may be true, once I have millions of rows in my table, maybe it would make the other choice, I haven't tested that.

But the reason it's bugging me is because when I'm first designing my tables and indexes, before I've had a chance to load the table with lots of test data, I typically will run sample queries like this to verify I've created good and useful indexes. If I see it's not using the indexes I expect it to, I start looking for something I've done wrong.

If it is really just a matter of not having data and statistics, and so it's just choosing arbitrarily (but obviously in some consistent way, like preferring the latest created), is there any temporary query planner option that would force it to try a little harder? I looked at the options and didn't see anything I thought looked helpful.

I'm running on PostgreSQL v11.10 in AWS RDB

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are no rows in the table (although the explain plan suggests there is one).  It doesn't matter which index is being used.  I'm surprised it is using an index at all.  Don't generalize index usage from trivially small tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, If it really is just a matter of having no data in the table, I was also surprised it would bother to use an index instead just a seq scan. I'll have to wait and test with a large amount of data. But as I said, had hoped to be able to reasonably verify I have good indexes the planner can use for specific queries without populating the table.

Comment: . . Because there is no data in the table, it might recognize that the statistics are all up-to-date, so it reads the index instead of the table because it is "smaller".  It is not really smaller, there is still a data page of I/O.  But this is an edge case.  I'm not sure if there is a tool that can spoof table sizes to see what plans the optimizer would generate on larger data.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a tool available that would push in statistics to simulate different data sizes and patterns, to see what choices it would make. I'm probably overthinking - and should just trust my index choices and the query planner until things start misbehaving :)

Comment: The planner is driven by statistics which is driven by data. No data, no statistics and really no planner. Also an index is only as useful as the data it is indexing. If the index  is not on the data that is most used or the data items are not sufficiently unique then it will not be of much help. To get what you want you will need to populate the table with test data and run appropriate test queries, preferably using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comments so far have summed it up, thanks.

This is just a result of having no data, so no statistics, and probably is just an arbitrary choice.

I'll update and maybe change the title accordingly once I've verified with data.